# SCSS/CSS All elements that are NOT children of an ID'd element

Tags: css, sass

```css
.thing {
  color: red;
}

/* Additional rules here to honour the below request. */
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="thing">Should be red</div>
  <div class="thing">Should be red</div>
  <div class="thing">Should be red</div>
  <div id="Excluder">
    <div class="thing">Should not be red</div>
    <div class="thing">Should not be red</div>
    <div class="thing">Should not be red</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make all elements with the class `thing` have a colour of red except for items within an element with the id `Excluder`

Is such a thing possible with CSS/SCSS?

Comment: With the given markup you can do `div:not(#Excluder) > .thing {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) property to set the `.thing` elements that are children of `#Excluder` to their initial value.

```css
.thing {
  color: red;
}

#Excluder>.thing {
  color: initial;
}


/* Additional rules here to honour the below request. */
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="thing">Should be red</div>
  <div class="thing">Should be red</div>
  <div class="thing">Should be red</div>
  <div id="Excluder">
    <div class="thing">Should not be red</div>
    <div class="thing">Should not be red</div>
    <div class="thing">Should not be red</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Codepen Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeGvax

```
.thing {
  color: red;
}

#Excluder {
  .thing {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

This will do what you want.

If you want not to set any color for `#Excluder .thing` , just set the color property unset or initial.

```
#Excluder {
    .thing {
        color: unset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `&` variable to reset the color of `.thing` elements within `#Excluder` elements:

```
.thing{
    color: red;

    #Excluder > &{
        color: initial;
    }
}
```